# How can I bind DataGrid Column to a property within an anonymous type as part of LINQ GroupBy?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datagrid

I've got a WPF project, which contains a DataGrid. Here is the grid:

```
<DataGrid Name="dgMyGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="120">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="File Name" Binding="{Binding source}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Count" Binding="{Binding count}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

As you can see, I'm hoping to bind the first column to a property called 'source' and the second column to a property called 'count'.

My data source for the datagrid is created like this:

```
var fileList = listFlaws.OrderBy(x => x.sourceFile)
                        .GroupBy(y => new {
                            sourcePath = y.sourceFilePath,
                            source = y.sourceFile,
                            count = listFlaws.Where(z => z.sourceFilePath == y.sourceFilePath).Count()
                        });

dgMyGrid.ItemsSource = fileList;
```

The datagrid is blank when I try and bind to the properties in the anonymous type. However, I do seem to be able to bind to the properties on the type within listFlaws, such as sourceFile. Unfortunately, the whole point of the anonymous type is to try and give me a way to bind a count property as well.

So how can I bind to the properties within the anonymous type, mainly 'source' and 'count'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you used `GroupBy`, `fileList` is a sequence of `Group` objects, not a sequence of your anonymous type. Since you're grouping by the anonymous object, that'll be in the `Key` property of the `Group`. That's what `GroupBy` does: The selector lambda returns a key, and `GroupBy` returns/yields/whatever a sequence of `Group` objects, representing the original sequence grouped by whatever set of keys your selector gave it.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="File Name" Binding="{Binding Key.source}" />
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Count" Binding="{Binding Key.count}" />
```

The `Group` itself is enumerable. If you were to bind that to an `ItemsSource` somewhere, that would enumerate the items from `listFlaws` that were grouped by the anonymous-typed key value for that `Group`, if you care about those.

For example,

```
var evenOdd = Enumerable.Range(1, 6)
              .GroupBy(y => (y & 1) == 0)
              ;
```

That will yield a sequence of the following two Groups:

```
Group.Key == false
((IEnumerable)Group) == [1, 3, 5]

Group.Key == true
((IEnumerable)Group) == [2, 4, 6]
```

Comment: Thanks. Completely forgotten I'd need the 'Key' word!